# pdfbox not rendering modified pdf file properly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using "pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC2.jar"

I have created a class which scales down the pdf content and creates new pdf with this content at specified co-ordinates.

My problem is if a pdf file has been modified and added new contents, Than this content is missing from the Scaled down file.

Following is my method:

```
public static String scaleInputPdf(String sourceFileName, float xpos,
        float ypos, float imgCtrlWidth, float imgCtrlHeight,
        PDRectangle pageSize) throws IOException {

    String workdir = "/tmp";

    File tmpDir = new File(workdir);
    if(! tmpDir.exists()) {
        tmpDir.mkdir();
    }

    String destPath = workdir + "/Result.pdf";

    PDDocument sourceDoc = null;
    try {
        // load the source PDF
        sourceDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(sourceFileName));

        // create a new PDF and add a blank page
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

        for (int sourcePageNo = 0; sourcePageNo < sourceDoc
                .getNumberOfPages(); sourcePageNo++) {

            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            page.setMediaBox(pageSize);

            doc.addPage(page);

            PDPage currentSourcePage = sourceDoc.getPage(sourcePageNo);

            PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc,
                    page, true, true, true);

            float scaleFactor = getScalingFactor(currentSourcePage,
                    imgCtrlWidth, imgCtrlHeight, pageSize);

            PDFormXObject form = null;

            // Create a Form XObject from the source document using
            // LayerUtility
            LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(doc);
            form = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(sourceDoc,
                    sourcePageNo);

            // draw a scaled form
            contents.saveGraphicsState();

            Matrix scalingMatrix = Matrix.getScaleInstance(scaleFactor,
                    scaleFactor);
            contents.transform(scalingMatrix);

            Matrix translatingMatrix = Matrix.getTranslateInstance(
                    xpos,
                    getYPosition(currentSourcePage, pageSize, ypos,
                            scaleFactor));
            contents.transform(translatingMatrix);

            contents.drawForm(form);

            contents.restoreGraphicsState();
            contents.close();

        }
        doc.save(destPath);
        doc.close();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (sourceDoc != null) {
            sourceDoc.close();

        }
    }
    System.err.println("Done! /n file is at following location=" +destPath);
    return destPath;

}

private static float getScalingFactor(PDPage sourcePage,
        float imgCtrlWidth, float imgCtrlHeight, PDRectangle pageSize) {

    PDRectangle imageSize = sourcePage.getMediaBox();

    if (imageSize.getHeight() > 792) {

        if (pageSize.equals(PDRectangle.LETTER)) {
            imgCtrlWidth = 838.8f; // 932 * 0.90
            imgCtrlHeight = 1018f; // 1132 *0.90
        } else if (pageSize.equals(PDRectangle.A4)) {
            imgCtrlWidth = 819f; // 910 * 0.90
            imgCtrlHeight = 972f; // 1080 * 0.90
        }
    }

    float scaleX = imgCtrlWidth / imageSize.getWidth();

    float scaleY = imgCtrlHeight / imageSize.getHeight();

    float scaleFactor = ((scaleX < scaleY) ? scaleX : scaleY);

    if (imageSize.getHeight() > 792 && scaleFactor > 0.88) {
        scaleFactor = 0.88f;
    }

    return scaleFactor;
}

private static float getYPosition(PDPage sourcePage,
        PDRectangle finalDocPageSize, float yMarginPos, float scaleFactor) {

    float yPos = yMarginPos;

    float imgHeight = sourcePage.getMediaBox().getHeight();

    PDRectangle cropBox = sourcePage.getCropBox();

    if (imgHeight > 792) {

        if (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() != 0) {

            yPos = cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + 40;
        }

    } else {

        yPos = (finalDocPageSize.getHeight() - (imgHeight * scaleFactor + yMarginPos));
    }

    return yPos;
}
}
```

In the attached image ModifiedFile 
[image: Modified file]
there is content at the right corner, which is missing from the ResultPDf from the above method.
[image: Result pdf from the above method]

Comment: The missing part contains the word "Annotation". Thus, I assume it actually *is* a pdf annotation. Annotations are **not** part of the regular content but are separate entities loosely associated with a page having their own contents. In contrast form XObjects  (as which you import the source page contents) cannot have annotations. Thus, they are ignored by your code. By the way, why do you use a 2.0.0 release candidate even though 2.0.0 has already been released?

Comment: We're at 2.0.4 now. RC2 is a year old. Makes me wonder why we worked so hard to make new releases LOL

Comment: First of all thankyou very much for responding :)

Comment: yes you are correct this is a comment annotation, As you say these entities are loosely associated , is this same true for external stamps added to the pdf also . is there any way of getting these annotations and stamps to a new pdf ?  I very much appreciate guys working at pdfbox , it is just that I haven't moved to the new version yet, this work was done a year ago when RC2 was the latest version and I got a feedback lately that some of the pdf with stamps are not getting scaled down. one solution is to  convert pdf into images but it increase new pdf file sizes a lot .

Comment: Just call pdPage.getAnnotations() and then setAnnotations().

Comment: Thankyou Tilman it solved the problem :)

Comment: @Sushantkumar Please delete the question or answer it yourself, I'm a bit lazy right now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following code in order to show annotation on new page with resize values :

List anotn =currentSourcePage.getAnnotations();

```
            for(PDAnnotation an :anotn) {
                PDRectangle rec = an.getRectangle();

                PDRectangle currentSourcePageMBox = currentSourcePage.getMediaBox();

                boolean isLandscape = currentSourcePageMBox.getWidth() > currentSourcePageMBox.getHeight();

                if(isLandscape) {

                    rec.setLowerLeftY(((rec.getLowerLeftY()) * scaleFactor) + 180 + 2 * ypos);
                    rec.setUpperRightY(((rec.getUpperRightY()) * scaleFactor) + 180 + 2*ypos);
                }
                else {
                    rec.setLowerLeftY(((rec.getLowerLeftY()) * scaleFactor) +  ypos);
                    rec.setUpperRightY(((rec.getUpperRightY()) * scaleFactor) +  ypos);
                }

                rec.setLowerLeftX((rec.getLowerLeftX() + xpos) * scaleFactor);
                rec.setUpperRightX((rec.getUpperRightX() + xpos ) * scaleFactor);                   

                an.setRectangle(rec);
            }

            // get all annotations and set on the new page.
            page.setAnnotations(currentSourcePage.getAnnotations());
```